# Richfaces XMLNS in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, richfaces, xml-namespaces

I use Richfaces in my Project and I really like the Kickass Code Completion in IntelliJ. But somehow I am not able to autocomplete the Richfaces Stuff. Here is my relevant part of my XHTML file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
template="layout/template.xhtml">
```

IntelliJ tells me, that it can not fetch the external ressource, because there is no XML at the Richfaces URL. All other Code Completions work. Has someone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to configure a mapping from the resource URI to the local file in `Settings` | `Resources`.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me into the right direction. Essentially I had to add "richfaces-ui.jar" from the /lib folder of my Seam project.

Comment: In my case, I had to manually add the URI `http://richfaces.org/rich` pointing to `C:\myLocalMavenRepo\org\richfaces\ui\richfaces-components-ui\4.3.1.Final\richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar!\META-INF\rich.taglib.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Also u can add the richfaces libraries to Project Structure | Libraries and add them to the package in Project Structure | Artifacts and will work